# Converting ((p↔q)→(p∧r)) to CNF

Tags: logic

In my solution, I work my way step by step, removing negations, however I feel like im one step away, but where I'm at doesnt coincide with the wolfram solution:

((p↔q)→(p∧r))

(~(p↔q)∨(p∧r)) →

(~((p→q)∧(q →p)) ∨(p∧r)) ↔

(~((~p ∨ q)∧(~q ∨p)) ∨(p∧r)) →,→

((~(~p ∨ q)∨~(~q ∨p)) ∨(p∧r)) de morgans laws

((p ∧ ~q)∨(q ∧~p) ∨(p∧r)) de morgans laws, double negation

((p ∧ ~q∧ q) ∨ (p ∧ ~q ∧~p) ∨(p∧r)) distributivity

((p ∨ ~q) ∨(p∧r)) law of the excluded middle,  commutativity

(p ∨ ~q ∨ p) ∧ (p ∨ ~q ∨ r) distributivity

(~p ∨ ~q ∨ r) ∧ (p ∨ q) this is the final answer obtained from wolfram, which doesnt match, did I make an error in the computation?

Comment: 7th line : the use of [distriutivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement) is wrong. It must be : $[((p ∧ \lnot q) ∨ q) ∧ ((p ∧ \lnot q) ∨ \lnot p)] ∨(p∧r)$

Comment: In addition, 8th line : $(p ∧ \lnot q ∧ q) \equiv (p \land F) \equiv F$.

Comment: ok, ill fix line 7 and keep applying distributive properties